# commenting out multiple lines of code with regular expressions

Tags: css, regex

I want to find every instance of a background image in a CSS document and comment it out:

```
background: url('images/test.jpg') no-repeat top left;
```

becomes

```
background: /*url('images/test.jpg')*/ no-repeat top left;
```

I'm having trouble escaping the * and / (don't want to comment out the entire background selector).

Comment: You'll need to describe which programming language or text editor you are using for flavors of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search for**:

```
(background)(.*)(url\('.*[^']'\))(.*)
```

**Replace with**:

```
$1$2/*$3*/$4
```

Answer (score 2):

couldn't you just put in the search box `url('images/test.jpg')` and in the replace box: `/*url('images/test.jpg')*/` (thus avoiding regular expressions at all)?
Setting the options 'search in:' to 'current document' and 'search for:' to 'source code', then hitting 'replace all'..

Comment: But each url will be different. image/test.jpg was just an example. Sorry, I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

search for

```
background:(\s*url\s*\([^)]+\))
```

replace with

```
background:/*$1*/
```

You shouldn't have to escape the * and / in the replacement text

Comment: You'd want to capture the whole bit, otherwise you've created an invalid CSS file.

Comment: @Tom, anything that follows the url(...) such as no-repeat top left will be left in tact.  This only comments-out the URL bit, nothing else.  That said, if there happened to be a background rule with nothing but the url in it, you could end up with some invalid CSS.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. My line usually looks like "background: url(xxx) 0 0 no-repeat;", so it confused me.